# How to suppress Launch Services alert message on OS X 10.10

Tags: objective-c, dialog, osx-yosemite, launch-services

I have something like:

```
LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme((__bridge CFStringRef)(urlschemeref), newHandler);
```

Up to OS X 10.9 it worked nicely and set the default URL handler to whatever I had in newHandler.

In Yosemite, Apple introduced a "security feature": a dialog box is displayed to user to confirm the change. Something like this:

[image: Do you want to change your default web browser to "Safari" or keep using "Chrome"?]

I know it's a bit far fetched, but maybe there is a way to suppress or "accept" that programmatically?

Or is there a better way to set URLScheme handlers in a headless context?